# Re-Enter CAS Mode to Edit Sim Later

Tags: the-sims-4

Anyone know if there is a way to re-enter Create a Sim mode to re-sculpt a sim? I know you can edit topical things like hairstyle, but I mean to go back and fully re-vamp a sim. I'm not happy with how one of mine turned out.

Google hasn't turned up anything; not sure if there's an object I can buy that I'm missing not seeing; I don't see anything in aspiration rewards, either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to bring up the cheat console.
2. Enter `testingcheats true`
3. Enter `cas.fulleditmode` (this enables you to make full edits, like when you start a new game)
4. Now click on a sim while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down. You should get an "Edit in CAS" option.
5. Click that option and you're ready to edit your sim.

Note that `testingcheats true` gives you access to all kinds of cheats on several objects when clicked with shift down (resetting sims, giving happy moods etc.)

Comment: Perfection. Wish there was a canon way of doing it, but until then, I'm saved!

Answer (score 1):

In the new patch testingcheats for some reason doesn't work, but I found this (sort of) alternative 
This doesn't work so nicely for sims you've already happily playing but you can also do the following:

1.Ensure family is out of world and go onto the household management tab.
2. Click your family and click the "edit" pencil
3. On CAS click "new sim" then "play with genetics"
4. Change relation to "sibling" then select "randomise twin"
This creates an identical, new, fully editable sim, although hair/facial hair, clothes, aspirations and traits would need to be put back in

Optional
5. Delete old sim and continue to edit identical sim (hence if you are already playing with them it isn't so great)

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the "Household Management" icon in the top right of your screen (preferably whilst in a town (i.e. Willow Creek))
2. Select your desired household you wish to change in the "Played Households" section
3. Press the blank plumbob (diamond) in the bottom left corner of the picture that appears (once your courser is on of it, it will turn green and display the words "Mark as Unplayed")
4. Press "Edit"
5. Modify your Sim(s) to your liking

(You'll have to go to the "Unplayed Households" section to retreive your sim(s))

Answer (score -1):

No it does not let you change the body or their voice of you click on the dresser it only lets you change the clothes hair accessories makeup walk type and aspirations

Answer (score -1):

I believe the cheats command has changed to `boolprop testingcheatsenabled true`. So, the procedure is as follows.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> while ingame
2. `testingcheatsenabled true` 3. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Click sim for menu, select the edit sim option

Answer (score -1):

If you go to a dresser ( if you don't have one, you'll have to buy one) click it, and then it should pop up some options.
One of them is " Plan outfits" click that one and it should bring you to Create a Sim Again!!

Answer (score -1):

1. Buy a dresser
2. click on the dresser
3. click on the option "Plan Outfits"
4. You will be taken back to Create a Sim and You can edit all of your gear.

Happy Gaming.

Comment: Your answer has already been given and it doesn't fully answer the question anyway. It's worth checking through the existing answers before posting one for future reference. :)

Answer (score -1):

For vampires, and regular sims, click on a mirror, and it should say change sim. With that, you can edit pretty much everything, exept for the slider for weight, and I think voice.

Answer (score -2):

There IS a canon way to do it!

1. Buy a dresser.
2. Click on it, and it should have a "Plan Outfits" option.
3. Click Plan Outfits and voila! Welcome back to Create-A-Sim!

Hope this helped :3

Comment: And you're saying this allows you to edit anything about the sim? As in not just the clothes- you could chance their face too? And nobody has tried this or noticed?

Answer (score -2):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
2. testingcheats on
3. cas.fulleditmode
4. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> click
5. Edit in CAS

Comment: Isn't this just a (currently) broken variant of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184063/88481?  (`on` doesn't seem to be a accepted in place of `true` anymore, though https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-sims-4/PC_Cheats still claims it's allowed...)

Answer (score -2):

CTRL + SHIFT + C

testingcheats on

SHIFT + click on selected simmer

Edit in "les"

When you are in "edit in les"

CTRL + SHIFT + C

cas.editfullmode

and then you can change anything you want :D

Answer (score -2):

- Testingcheats true
- CAS.fulleditmode
- Click sim
- Hit Edit in CAS
- Once in CAS, the entire family will appear.
- Click body to edit body, face to edit face. etc. You can also add another sim. You can add relationship.
- Once complete hit the Check button.

I know this works because I edited the Landgraab family. The daddy
aged up, I didn't want him to so I used this method to make him an
adult again and his wife a young adult since he obviously was way
older than she.

Also, I created 2 more teens and made them both their kids. Why?
(they are the secret that was being held)

If you don't believe me, go to communities, put in my id vejai2 and
you will see the Landgraab family. once 3 now 5.  :d

I also did this on one of my sims who was grossly deformed when he
turned a teen.  His upper body was maxed out to muscles, his legs also
but his pelvis and buttock area looked like a kid's.
So of course Dr vejai2 had to come to the rescue and now he's perfect symetry!

Answer (score -3):

ctlr+shift

testingcheats true 
                                                                                   CAS.fulleditmode                                                                                                                                                                   it workkkssssssssss